# how to read two or more file , possibly from different buckets and output the result into a new file s3?

Tags: amazon-s3

based on the s3 documentation, there is not a way to add to an existing file in s3 without overwriting the original file. in that case, is there a way to combine two file from say two different buckets and dump it into the third bucket? I've tried and doing this locally but would like to migrate this process to aws.

Comment: The S3 REST API has no function to combine two files.  You will need to read the two files and upload the resulting combined file.  Where you do it is largely a matter of convenience.

Comment: @Anon Coward - thanks.